# 500 Internal Server Error WAMP PhpStorm

Tags: php, wamp, internal-server-error

I'm currently developing a PHP project in PhpStorm using WAMP.

When I run my project I am getting '500 internal server error'. This error shows when I make code changes to a certain php file within my project. For example, I added a name attribute to a html input tag, and this resulted in '500 internal server error'.

Can somebody please advice on this error.

```
<?php
    require_once 'databaseLoginCredentials.php';
    $connection = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
    if ($connection->connect_error)
    {
        die("Connection failed " . $connection->connect_error);
    }
    $sql = ("SELECT * FROM tbl_patientdetails pd INNER JOIN tbl_doctors dr ON pd.pd_registerDoctorId = dr.dr_Id");
    $result = $connection->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0 ) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
        {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td><button name="btn-edit" id="btn-edit" value="Edit" onclick="populatePatientDetailsForm()">' . 'Edit' .'</button></td>';
            echo '<td><button name="btn-delete" id="btn-delete" value="Delete" onclick="">' . 'Delete' .'</button></td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row->pd_id . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row->pd_forename . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row->pd_lastname . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row->pd_dateOfBirth . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row->pd_gender . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row->dr_id . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row->pd_address . ' </td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row->pd_postcode . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row->pd_phoneNumber .'</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row->pd_email .'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    } else
    {
        echo "0 Patients Returned";
    }
    $connection->close();
    ?> <!--END OF PHP-->
```

```
require_once 'databaseLoginCredentials.php';

if ($_POST['btn-submit']) {

    $id = $_POST['txt-patientId'];
    $forename = $_POST['txt-forename'];
    $surname = $_POST['txt-surname'];
    $dateOfBirth = $_POST['txt-dateOfBirth'];
    $gender = $_POST['ddl-gender'];
    $doctorId = $_POST['ddl-doctor'];
    $address = $_POST['txt-address'];
    $postcode = $_POST['txt-postcode'];
    $phoneNumeber = $_POST['txt-phoneNumber'];
    $email = $_POST['txt-email'];


    $conn = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: (" . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = ("Update tbl_patientdetails
            SET pd_forename = '$forename',
                pd_lastname = '$surname',
                pd_dateOfBirth = '$dateOfBirth',
                pd_gender = '$gender',
                pd_registerDoctorId = '$doctorId',
                pd_address = '$address',
                pd_postcode = '$postcode',
                pd_phoneNumber = '$phoneNumeber',
                pd_email = '$email',
            WHERE pd_id = '$id'");

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

        echo "Success: ' .$id' ',' ' .$forename' Please redirect me Joe";
    } else {
        echo " error Joe: " . $conn->error;
        //Return to patiend Details page
    }

    $conn->close();
}
```

[WAMP ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mtSk.png)

Comment: Can you provide your php ?

Comment: You need to post more detail. You should find a more detailed error in the apache error log. Also, post your php.

Comment: @BrianKeller-Heikkila as been added. Can you advise how to access the apache error log?

Comment: @Nirnae PHP snippets have now bee added, thanks.

Comment: Posting images of PHP code that are linked externally is not helpful to others who might have your problem. Post the PHP code directly in the question. Check out [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As far as accessing the apache error logs, I'm not familiar with WAMP setups, but I'm sure you can google it pretty easily.

Comment: Is there an htaccess file in use? if there is have any changed been made recently to it or the server configuration?

Comment: @BrianKeller-Heikkila Cheers for the advise, code now available.

Comment: @SpacePhoenix I'm unsure as to what you mean by in use? But I haven't made any modifications to any wamp files.

Comment: I suggest debugging with xdebug -- trace line by line until you will see where the error occurs. Right now it could be in SQL query (at least this sort of behaviour I saw when worked with SQL Server via ODBC driver directly).

Comment: @LazyOne tried this, and it doesn't hit any off the break points.

Comment: You say the error happens when you amend a piece of HTML **but you dont specify which piece of HTML**. Show the piece of HTML before the change i.e. no error and then show the amended HTML where you receive the error.

Comment: If by WAMP you mean WAMPServer the logs are all stored in `\wamp\logs` and can be accessed using the wampmanager menus

Comment: @RiggsFolly Today I have been promoted to install the latest version of PhpStorm 10.0. I have also reinstalled WAMP and my project now seems to be working. However, my WAMPserver is displayed as a yellow/orange icon and states 'Server offiline'. When I attempt to 'put online', I get the error shown in the post.

Comment: If you have a yellow icon then that means that it is not starting correctly make sure there are no other programs using port 80 and 443 like skype or something....Also the error could point to a content encoding error.

Comment: Turns out that 'SQL server reporting services' was blocking port 80. I have disabled the service and now WAMP runs fine (Green).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that 'SQL server reporting services' was blocking port 80. I have disabled the service and now WAMP runs fine (Green). I'm not confident that this was the only issue ...